# Significance of difference between CAR of two portfolios

Tags: statistical-significance, t-test, econometrics

[image]

I'm currently studying the paper of Chou and Lin (2015). In his research he calculate the difference of CAR (cumulative abnormal return) of two porfolios in several event windows. In the results he showed that each event windows has different significancy. I wasn't sure how he determine the significance of the  CAR difference for each event windows, what sample data did he use? is is the ARt?

Comment: Please give a citation for the paper (not just a link, as those can break). It’s not obvious which paper you mean. I’m getting lots of hits for medical papers.

Comment: Chou, Robin K. and Lin, Chu-Bin, Investor Sentiment, Market Timing and Seasoned Equity Offering (August 2015). Available at SSRN: https://ssrn.com/abstract=2646417 or http://dx.doi.org/10.2139/ssrn.2646417